# GTX 970 keeps crashing the system, but only once per session

Tags: windows-10, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm having a problem with my Nvidia GTX 970 that has been annyoing me for several years now: whenever I run a game, the system crashes after somewhat between 5 and 15 minutes. Sometimes it automatically reboots, sometimes you have to press the reset button. Now here's the strange part: after reboot and restarting the game, I can play for as long as I want without any further problems. I just did a test and let the game run over night, no crashes. It's just that you need to run into this annoying first crash each time you use the card which is really frustrating. Did someone run (and maybe solved) similar issues?

Comment: I started to have a very similar issue on my upgraded setup. Can I ask how you determined that it's the GPU's fault?  Also, if you look in your Event log, do you see any WHEA-Logger "error 1" events?

Comment: @DmitryBrant I tested with a different graphics card (Radeon), everything worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need is a complete fresh install of your driver. This is quite easy.
Citing from [ubisoft.com](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-GB/Article/000063728). If you need to see the images inorder to proceed, head to that website.

> Nvidia offers an easy way to perform a clean installation of your drivers. Here's how to proceed:
>
> - Head to the [download section of the Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk) to select and download your driver.
> - Once you have downloaded the executable, double-click on it to start the installation.
> - Follow the on-screen instructions until presented with the Installation options window.
> - Select the box labelled Custom (Advanced) then hit Next.
> - On the next screen, you will be given a choice of components to install (These should all be ticked by default, and if you are unsure,
>   leave them that way).
> - Under the Select driver component table, tick the box Perform a clean installation and click Next.
>
> ​- Complete the installation, then restart your computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to be a driver-related issue. The problem occurs with Windows 10, Windows 7 and also in Linux. I also tried another PSU. I don't know, it feels like a software bug, but in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, contacted Nvidia support and solved the problem this way (Nvidia support answer):

1. Run the following 4 commands from terminal (cmd/powershell), administrator mode:

```
    sfc /scannow
    dism /online /cleanup-image /CheckHealth
    dism /online /cleanup-image /ScanHealth
    dism /online /cleanup-image /RestoreHealth
```

2. Perform clean uninstallation of the drivers with Nvidia's "CleanUp-Tool" tool and restart the computer.
   `https://developer.nvidia.com/cleanup-tool`
3. Perform clean installation (flag clean install during installation) of Nvidia drivers:
   `https://www.nvidia.it/Download/Find.aspx?lang=it`

Answer (score -1):

You may need to Update the drivers, Or either you have corrupted driver, If you have an up to date and no corrupted Drivers, You can troubleshoot it or replace it if you are saving up.